# Meaning of "handbags" in the context of a fight

Tags: meaning-in-context, british-english

Apparently a tussle between two English footballers was [described by an official spokesperson](http://www.metro.co.uk/sport/football/883366-samir-nasri-and-emmanuel-frimpong-post-match-clash-was-just-handbags) as

> 'I was there. There was no punches thrown. There was a lot of noise.
>   Samir was talking in French, Manu wasn’t. They didn’t touch. **It was
>   handbags.** There were words and that happens after most games,' he
>   said.

Is this a BrE usage?

Comment: Found this question while trying to decipher a live blog entry for a World Cup match. So another example of usage:  Corner come in and there's anear-post flick but Moreno in stretching for the header pushes Pletikosa over and handbags are taken out in the six-yard box with some shoving and slapping as the referee awards Croatia a foul.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Wiktionary:

> In British slang a fight where the protagonists are unable or
>   unwilling to seriously hurt each other is commonly refered to as a
>   handbag fight, in reference to the way girls fight by hitting each
>   other with their handbags.

Update: I found this reference by searching for "handbags at dawn", but it turns out I could also have found it by searching for "handbags fight", so actually this *is* a question that could be answered by a simple search.

Comment: "unable or unwilling to seriously hurt each other ... hitting each other with their handbags" Have you seen the size of handbags today?  :^)

Answer (score 3):

It's a contraction of 'handbags at dawn'. This phrase is itself a variation of 'pistols at dawn' which was a typical way of fighting a duel. The phrase 'handbags at dawn' evokes a mental image of old ladies using their handbags as crude bludgeons and implies the participants weren't really serious about inflicting harm on each other.

Comment: I've also heard the term, "Handbags at five / ten paces" used, which backs up this usage as being derived from a duel.